# C++ SymGetLineFromAddr has error code 126

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wrote a wrapper around some WINAPI functions. However, `SymGetLineFromAddr` always fails and has a error of 126. After doing some research, it seems like it is because `SymInitalize` is either not being called or failing. Debugging shows that `SymInitalize` is in fact, not failing. What's even more confusing is that `SymFromAddr` works perfectly fine. So why is `SymGetLineFromAddr` always faling with code 126?

```cpp
class debug_state
{
    // held for caching
    SYMBOL_INFO* symbol;
    IMAGEHLP_LINE* line;
    HANDLE process;
    bool is_init = false;
public:
    static constexpr int MAX_LEN = 1024;

    inline void init()
    {
        if (is_init)
            return;

        process = GetCurrentProcess();

        SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);

        symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO*)calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_LEN, 1);
        symbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_LEN;
        symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);

        line = (IMAGEHLP_LINE*)malloc(sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE));
        line->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE);

        is_init = true;
    }

    inline SYMBOL_INFO* get_info_of(intptr_t ptr)
    {
        init();
        SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(ptr), 0, symbol);
        return symbol;
    }

    inline IMAGEHLP_LINE* get_line_of(intptr_t ptr)
    {
        init();
        DWORD tmp;
        if (!SymGetLineFromAddr(process, (DWORD)(ptr), &tmp, line))
        {
            DWORD d = GetLastError();
            std::cout << d;
        }
        return line;
    }
};
```

Comment: And _error code 126_ means exactly what in that context? Can you add that information to the question please. Most people rarely remember just those numbers ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've fixed my questions a bit. Also I have no clue what error code 126 is, that's just what you get from calling `GetLastError`.

Comment: 126 is usually a bad or missing DLL if I remember correctly. [Looked it up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). Officially `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. Not sure how that applies in this context.

Comment: What if you're missing the symbol information? Have you checked the return code from `SymInitialize`

Comment: @user4581301 126 bad/missing DLL should also occur on the `SymFromAddr` method, no? And if missing symbol info, same thing should occur.

Comment: Is this a 64 bit build? (In which case you need [`SymGetLineFromAddr64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symgetlinefromaddr64).)

Comment: @PaulSanders `SymGetLineFromAddr` is a macro, which expands to `SymGetLineFromAddr64`

Comment: In which case `(DWORD)(ptr)` is a lossy operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `SymFromAddr` works perfectly fine.

It works because it doesn't truncate its pointer argument:

```cpp
SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(ptr), 0, symbol);
//                   ^^^^^^^^^ preserves 64 bits of information
```

Contrast that with the call to `SymGetLineFromAddr`:

```cpp
SymGetLineFromAddr(process, (DWORD)(ptr), &tmp, line)
//                          ^^^^^^^ truncate to 32 bits
```

This only passes the lower 32 bits of the pointer value into the API call. That works as long as you are using it with a 32bit process. For a 64bit process, the upper half of the information is lost. You should be using this instead:

```cpp
SymGetLineFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(ptr), &tmp, line)
```